# Can't reach nodes in host LAN from ICS Internet Connection Sharing client VM in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, nat

Currently I have an Ubuntu VM that is set up with an internal network virtual switch, that is connected via ICS Internet Connection Sharing with the host's Ethernet connection. This puts the VM on a 192.168.137.xxx internal NAT IP address and I can't connect to PCs in the host LAN with 192.168.0.xxx IP addresses. I need to be able to connect to 192.168.0.50:9182 for Prometheus data, from 192.168.0.49's internal NAT address of 192.168.137.15 for example. I cannot ping from the VM to the target IP, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bridged Adapter [image: simply go into the VirtualBox settings for that VM]

Then your virtual machine will get its own IP on the local network.